# How to apply multiple auto fixes with nvim LSP

Tags: neovim, nvim-lspconfig

In nvim, using LSP, i want to be able to apply a 'fix all of the same type' similar to what can be done in VSCode (see picture). How would one go about adding this to LSP code actions?

Edit: I know this can be done using COC. But i want it for LSP.
[image: VSCode example]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language server you are using, in my current NeoVim configuration I'm running both ESLint and tsserver and with a default configuration of ESLint in my root of my project, I get these types of code action.

Assuming you are using lspconfig plugin you need to make sure you have the server configured :

```
local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
capabilities.textDocument.completion.completionItem.snippetSupport = true
require('lspconfig')['tsserver'].setup {
  on_attach = function() end,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}
require('lspconfig')['eslint'].setup {
  on_attach = function() end,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}
```

You can then run in neovim : `:lua vim.lsp.buf.code_action()` in command mode (`n`)

You need both LSP installed manually

Ref :

- https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig#quickstart
- https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#eslint
- https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/doc/server_configurations.md#tsserver

*N.B. You should probably add your keymap related to LSP in the on_attach callback*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually have the default code action of "removed unused declaration for c" what i don't have is the "apply all fixes of type X" or similar.